# Форматирование массива

Tags: php, php7

Есть массив:

```
   <?php
            $students=array(
                "1" => array (
                    'name' => 'Богатырев Сергей',
                    'age' => '18',
                    'gpoup' => '20po1',
                    'like_skills' => ("PHP")
                ),
                "1" => array (
                    'name' => 'Eфименко Анна',
                    'age' => '19',
                    'gpoup' => '20po1',
                    'like_skills' => ("MySQL")
                ),
                "2" => array (
                    'name' => 'Наумов Владислав',
                    'age' => '18',
                    'gpoup' => '20po2',
                    'like_skills' => ("C++")
                ),
                "2" => array (
                    'name' => 'Безликая Ангелина',
                    'age' => '20',
                    'gpoup' => '20po2',
                    'like_skills' => ("PHP")
                ),
                "3" => array (
                    'name' => 'Темерязева Кристина',
                    'age' => '19',
                    'gpoup' => '20po3',
                    'like_skills' => ("Java")
                ),
            );
            
            foreach($students as $s=>$value)
            {
                $go[$value["name"]]=$s;
                $go[$value["aa"]]=$go;
            }
            print_r($go);
    ?>
```

Как сделать красивый(форматированный) вывод не используя print_r, var_dump? по типу группа: такая, имя: такое

Comment: Про вывод не скажу, использую как раз print_r, но вот одинаковые названия ключей - некошерно. Надеюсь, это у вас тут только для примера. Иначе, что по-вашему выведется на экран, если попросить к выдаче `$students['1']['name']`? Богатырев Сергей или Ефименко Анна?

Comment: @Quazimorda это для примера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сформируйте из каждого подмассива строку, затем выведите её при помощи конструкции [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php). Там где нужен перевод на новую строку добавьте константу PHP_EOL.

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b2c785c939b55ae97a6ef8cd64b70903b263356

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); 

// Немного поправил массив
$students = [
    [
        'name' => 'Богатырев Сергей',
        'age' => '18',
        'group' => '20po1',
        'like_skills' => 'PHP'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Eфименко Анна',
        'age' => '19',
        'group' => '20po1',
        'like_skills' => 'MySQL'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Наумов Владислав',
        'age' => '18',
        'group' => '20po2',
        'like_skills' => 'C++'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Безликая Ангелина',
        'age' => '20',
        'group' => '20po2',
        'like_skills' => 'PHP'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Темерязева Кристина',
        'age' => '19',
        'group' => '20po3',
        'like_skills' => 'Java'
    ],
];

foreach ($students as $key => $student) {
    /*
    if (array_key_first($students) !== $key) {
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
    */

    $str = 'Студент #' . ++$key . PHP_EOL;

    $str .= ' Фамилия/Имя: ';
    $str .= $student['name'];
    $str .= PHP_EOL;

    $str .= ' Возраст: ';
    $str .= $student['age'];
    $str .= PHP_EOL;

    $str .= ' Группа: ';
    $str .= $student['group'];
    $str .= PHP_EOL;

    $str .= ' Навыки: ';
    $str .= $student['like_skills'];
    $str .= PHP_EOL;

    echo $str . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: вывода нет, почему ругается на функцию array_key_first?

Comment: Значит версия php устаревшая, вырежите этот участок вместе с if

Comment: ошибка пропала, но вывода все равно нет

Comment: Где запускаете? В браузере?
Попробуйте после <?php добавить две строки:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

Comment: в браузере, foreach ($students as $key => $student) {

    $str = 'Студент #' . ++$key . PHP_EOL;

    $str = ' Фамилия/Имя: ';

Comment: не помогло, все так же только без if

Comment: Поправил код, скопируйте и попробуйте запустить ещё раз.

Comment: вот теперь работает, а в чем причина была?

Comment: В начале кода не было тега <?php.

Comment: Если мой ответ помог, выберите его как решение и поставьте стрелку вверх, плиз ^_^

Comment: Ага, и еще такой вопрос: нужно отобразить студентов у которых скилл PHP, с помощью чего это сделать? нужно создавать запрос?

Comment: В цикле добавить if с проверкой $student['like_skills'] === 
'PHP'. Код https://ideone.com/EMJu5x

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь!